# How do you chain Eloquent methods in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Using Laravel and mySQL - I'm trying to query a collection to return an array of entries sorted by the column 'course_id' and only the entries that have the same 'user_id'. I keep getting a '500 internal server error'.

I've tried different ways of doing it and also been reading the Eloquent docs but still stuck!

```
Route::get('roadmap/{id}', function ($user_id) {
  return RoadmapCourse::where('user_id', $user_id)->sortBy('course_id'); 
});
```

It works fine if I take off the sortBy():

```
  return RoadmapCourse::where('user_id', $user_id)->get();
```

But i'm trying to sort it by 'course_id'.

Thanks!

Comment: Were you looking for `orderBy()` instead of `sortBy()`?

Comment: Aha! `return RoadmapCourse::where('user_id', $user_id)->orderBy('course_id')->get();` works! Thanks. I'm not sure why orderBy() isn't mentioned in the docs? https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#available-methods

Comment: It is though, https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#retrieving-models, section `Adding Additional Constraints`

Comment: `orderBy()` does the ordering on SQL level (`ORDER BY desc`). sortBy does only sorts after fetching from the database

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

Comment: Btw, that's the manual for `Collections` you posted, use the manual for [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent)

Comment: Yeah thanks! I was looking in the wrong place! I'm a noob, glad you guys are here!!!

Comment: @djunehor Thanks, not sure why the original code didn't work then? It still should have sorted it after returning from the DB shouldn't it?

Comment: You were calling `sortBy` before `get()`. `sortBy()` only works on Laravel collection. So you must have called `get()` which returns a collection, before calling `sortBy()`. Something like `return RoadmapCourse::where('user_id', $user_id)->get()->sortBy('course_id');` will work.

Comment: Ok thanks, I understand now.

Comment: I think the comments and answers have solved this issue, but I'll add my thoughts. Understanding when you have a `Builder` instance, vs a `Collection` vs a single model instance is imperative to using Laravel effectively. This 500 server error you were getting likely would have said "Call to undefined method `sortBy()` on `Builder`" (or similar). It takes a bit of digging/experience to know what you have, and what methods return what, but wrapping a variable in `dd()` will show you its class (`Builder`, `Collection`, `Model`, etc), so in the meantime, use that to debug and learn :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with `orderBy()` instead of `sortBy()`:

return RoadmapCourse::where('user_id', $user_id)->orderBy('course_id','asc')->get();